# Remove id from php url with .htaccess

Tags: php, url, url-rewriting

I'm trying to remove the id's from the url's to make then a bit more friendly:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^cat/([a-zA-Z0-9---_]+)$ browse.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z0-9---_]+)$ item.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^products/([a-zA-Z0-9---_]+)&history=view$ item.php?id=$1&history=view
```

Comment: You need to show us what the URI currently looks like and what it should look like

Comment: Actually I also want the cat/ and products/ out of the url

The itempage:
https://mokum.nu/products/oude-logo-barspiegel-ajax-401

to

https://mokum.nu/oude-logo-barspiegel-ajax

and the category page:
https://mokum.nu/cat/afc-ajax-296

to

https://mokum.nu/afc-ajax